# Is there a way to set the image scaling method in reST/Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, image-scaling

when I use the :scale: property on my pixel art, its very blurry. How can i change the scaling method to nearest neighbor for sharper scaling in Sphinx/reST?

Comment: Sphinx itself is not an image manipulation program. You can, however, specify [options for an image](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) or perhaps try the extension [sphinx.ext.imgconverter](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/imgconverter.html).

Comment: @StevePiercy I re-phrased my question.

Comment: Your update does not change my comment. The `:scale:` option is more of a resize or zoom than a true scale feature.

Comment: I want it to rescale/zoom using the nearest neighbor method of rescaling

Comment: Your reply still does not change my first comment. I cannot help further.

Comment: Image scaling is done by the viewing agent (browser, PDF viewer, LaTeX). You cannot select the scaling method in rST. Consider pre-processing the images or an image-rewriting extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with Sphinx. You need to preprocess the image with a graphic tool, not with a documentation tool. For example, ImageMagick has various resize interpolation methods including [nearest](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/misc/#nearest).

To clarify what `:scale:` actually does: For example, for HTML output, `:scale:` option only set new dimensions to `<img>` - doesn't actually resize the image.

For example, if `img/foo.png` has 500x300 px

```
.. image:: img/foo.png
   :scale: 50%
```

in HTML will be

```
<img src="../_images/foo.png"
     style="width: 250.0px; height: 150.0px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:width:` option:

```
.. _target to image:

.. figure:: /img/logo.png
   :alt: Logo
   :align: center
   :width: 240px

   Link me!
```

I'm using sphinx and docxbuilder to generate MS Word documentation and using the `:width:` option it was possible to resize the image without distorting it.

Reference: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/cross-referencing-with-sphinx.html